# Styled system and responsive props - Object approach generates inverse media queries

Tags: responsive-design, responsive, styled-components, custom-properties, styled-system

I created some custom components using `styled-components` lib and extended them with built in `spacer` from `styled-system` to inherit responsive props.

`const CustomContainer = styled.div<SpaceProps & LayoutProps>(compose(layout, space));`

These are custom breakpoints:

```
const breakpoints: Breakpoints = ['600px', '900px', '1200px', '1536px'];

breakpoints.sm = breakpoints[0];
breakpoints.md = breakpoints[1];
breakpoints.lg = breakpoints[2];
breakpoints.xl = breakpoints[3];
```

Now instead of array approach of passing responsive props, i.e. `width=['100%', '50%']` where `100%` would match first breakpoint etc, I passed an object which is more intuitive:

`padding={_: '50%', md: '100%'}` I would expect to have `50%` applied by default, and for `md` and down to have `100%` but it inverts media queries behind.

It by default applies `media (min-width: 900px)` query on component instead of
`media (max-width: 900px)`. And I could not make it behave as I want. Thus I have '100%`width on large screens because of mentioned media query, and bellow it applied`50%`.

Could not find any acceptable solution or create it to use in most intuitive way as object approcah where key defines desired breakpoint AND DOWN (i.e. max-width).

Any help